# Applying css style to all asp.net textboxes and Html Inputs of type text

Tags: css, input, textbox, stylesheet

I'm using asp.net website and I need to apply css style to all text boxes and html Input with type text in one place.
I hope to help me in this issue ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```
[type=text] {
    color:Red;
    border: 1px solid black;   
}
```

This will apply that style to any element that is an input of type text. This will also work with the ASP text box control because that renders out as an input with a type of text.

Answer (score 1):

The above CSS will show:

> Error "Unexpected Character Sequence.Expected a selecter for style Rule."

You have to write the following code:

```
input[type=”text”] { 
    color:Red; 
    border: 1px solid black;   
}
```